# How to convert this curl in meteor HTTP Package?

Tags: curl, meteor, soap

```
curl --data @login.xml https://xxxxx/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1.
```

How to change this curl request into a HTTP GET call? or else is that any way to call this curl in Meteor directly.

login.xml contains

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <MAGE:login xmlns:MAGE="http://xxxxxx/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1">
        <MAGE:username>xxxxxxxx</MAGE:username>
        <MAGE:apiKey>xxxxxxxxx</MAGE:apiKey>
    </MAGE:login>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

i want to call the curl like this :

```
HTTP.get("https://domain/v1/query?v=20150910&lang=en&query=", {
 headers: {
   Authorization: "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
meteor add zardak:soap
```

Install this package in root of application folder. then try with those following codes.

```
var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
var args = {name: 'value'};

try {
  var client = Soap.createClient(url);
  var result = client.MyFunction(args);

 console.log(result);
}
catch (err) {
  if(err.error === 'soap-creation') {
    console.log('SOAP Client creation failed');
  }
  else if (err.error === 'soap-method') {
    console.log('SOAP Method call failed');
  }

}
```

You can do any soap api calls with these functions. for more details visit : https://atmospherejs.com/zardak/soap

Comment: I don't understand -- Client.MyFunction(args) -- where is this defined, what is this, why is it called MyFunction?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of some code where I do a http GET

```
var opts = {npmRequestOptions: {rejectUnauthorized:false, jar: true, contentType: 'text/plain'},
    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer "+p.access_token}
};
var url = p.protocol+'://'
    +p.guardiumIP+':'
    +p.guardiumPort
    +'/restAPI/policy';
console.log("url="+url);
var curlcmd = "curl -k --header \"Authorization:Bearer"+p.access_token+"\"";
curlcmd += " -i -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -X GET ";
curlcmd += url;
console.log("cmd would be "+curlcmd);
HTTP.get(url,opts,PoliciesCB);
```

You'll notice in the code that I also build a curl command and log it to the console, in case I need to use curl manually to look closer at the data coming back.

In its minimal form it would look like this:

```
var opts = {npmRequestOptions: {rejectUnauthorized:false, jar: true, contentType: 'text/plain'},
    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer "+p.access_token}
};
var url = p.protocol+'://'
    +p.guardiumIP+':'
    +p.guardiumPort
    +'/restAPI/policy';
var curlcmd = "curl -k --header \"Authorization:Bearer"+p.access_token+"\"";
HTTP.get(url,opts,PoliciesCB);
```

Comment: This needs to be run from a server method for the npmRequestOptions to work